# Style issues when adding more css style

Tags: html, css

I am facing that issue here with my navbar.
I am adding a style nav-link and notification
My fonts become bigger and it starts using the active btn style.

[image]

```
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link, notification" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="
          ['/company/conversation']">Communication <span class="badge-com">3</span> </a>
</li>
```

this is what I add to style

```
.notification {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 26px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.notification:hover {
  background: red;
}

.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

What are the ways to solve that issue?
thanks!!!

Comment: what's `[routerLinkActive]` ? are you suing some templating engine ?

Comment: @mrid , this is angular, brother! I am working as a frontend in a company, so this is not the code I write, but they do it. I just do the html + css

Answer (score 1):

```
.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px; /* added font-size */
}
```

in code its batch-com and in CSS it's batch. I wonder how it worked.

Comment: yeah, i just copied wrong one. but no worries, it is solved now and thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

THere was a badge class already, so I just had to add some colors there and it is all done.